# Simple transition for React component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-transitions, transition

I have a React component that I show/hide based on a button toggle from within its parent component. Instead of just appearing/disappearing on the page, I would like to animate the mounting and unmounting of the component to make it look as if it was sliding down from, and back into the parent. The parent is always visible. [image]

One important note is that there are also components within the first child. One of my attempts involving CSS transitions have resulted in these children being stuck in place when the first child slides up/down. Additionally, Child has no fixed height -- it could be 100px or 1000px.

This is my only animation in the application, so I don't really want to get anything too heavy to drive it. I'm struggling to find what other people are using for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this with a small package called [react-animate-height](https://github.com/Stanko/react-animate-height).

```
<div>
  <AnimateHeight
    duration={ 500 }
    height={ height } 
  >
    <Child />
  </AnimateHeight>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For that kind of simple animations I generally use [CSSTransation](http://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/css-transition). The idea is pretty simple, this component will attach some classes to your element depending on the component state (mounting, unmounting,...), and you have to provide css for the animation.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the direction. I've had another go using this method and getting stuck again with creating a smooth slide for Child while also having Child's children slide with it. Do you have any pointers to achieve this effect? I have just been using the `height` property, without success. As an additional challenge, Child has no fixed height -- it could be 100px, or 1000px.